# XLPagerTabStrip doesn't cover the full width

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, xlpagertabstrip

Hi so basically my xlpagertabstrip doesn't cover the full width especially if the width goes to the ipad size. I already tried different methods from the past problems with the same issue to no avail such as changing the buttonbarviewcontroller's class. Here is the code

```
settings.style.buttonBarBackgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019754, green: 0.2745098174, blue: 0.3019607961, alpha: 1)
    settings.style.buttonBarItemBackgroundColor = .white
    settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1019607857, green: 0.2784313858, blue: 0.400000006, alpha: 1)
    settings.style.buttonBarItemFont = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    settings.style.selectedBarHeight = 2.0
    settings.style.buttonBarMinimumLineSpacing = 0
    settings.style.buttonBarItemTitleColor = .black
    settings.style.buttonBarItemsShouldFillAvailableWidth = true
    settings.style.buttonBarLeftContentInset = 0
    settings.style.buttonBarRightContentInset = 0

    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.setNeedsLayout()
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

and this is what it looks like right now.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB61r.png)

Thank you for anybody who can help.

Comment: Have you set IBOutlets in storyboard properly ?

Comment: @MahendraGP Yes thanks for helping me out. This has really stumped me. Has this happened to you?

Comment: Yes, I was also not able to deal with this issue in past but then read its documentation and then found the solution.

Comment: @MahendraGP what was the solution for you?

Comment: @Mahendra, what was the solution?

Comment: @gbenroscience, I didn't use this:(